# Export from one Google WorkSpace email account and import into another

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I'm a little confused about Google's Data Migration Services and exporting and importing email from one WorkSpace email account to another. I'm a super admin on a WorkSpace account.

I need to export email from one email account and import into another. The email accounts are from two different domains, but are set up in the same WorkSpace account. `olddomain.org` is the original domain, and `newdomain.org` has been added.

For some reason, the olddomain.org shows Gmail is not active, but email for `olddomain.org` is being used. (I am currently forwarding email from `user1@olddomain.org` to `user2@newdomain.org`.)

[image]

I want to export all mail from `user1@olddomain.org` and import into `user2@newdomain.org`.

I've looked at the Data Migration Services https://support.google.com/a/answer/9476255 but that doesn't appear to help with copying email between individual accounts.

What is the best way to do this export/import? Will Data Migration Services work? It seems like copying via IMAP is the best way, but I don't see how to do that for an individual account, not the entire WorkSpace.

Is GYB a option? https://github.com/GAM-team/got-your-back

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is a complex troubleshooting question that's outside the site scope. I do want you to solve your problem. 
This aporoach makes the most sense: [Transfer email data when you delete a user](https://knowledge.workspace.google.com/kb/how-to-transfer-email-data-when-you-delete-a-user-000004308). Actions already taken may need to be adjusted or undone. Please review the link I shared. If you'd like to [continue this in a chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150466/discussion-on-question-by-bluedogranch-export-from-one-google-workspace-email-ac) I will try to assist further.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150466/discussion-on-question-by-bluedogranch-export-from-one-google-workspace-email-ac); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Per the comment above [please continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150466/discussion-on-question-by-bluedogranch-export-from-one-google-workspace-email-ac)